# We're sorry, but something went wrong. - with Rails, Apache, Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, webrick

I have `Rails` 3.2.3 with `Apache` and `Passenger`.

I have a project working in development mode.
When I switch the project to production mode (`Passenger` standard)
it gives me an `HTTP Error 500`:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

This happens even with `WEBrick`.
Can somebody help me?

**Edit**:

My production environment file:
http://pastebin.com/ZAudSzkc

Comment: Have you properly build your production envirnoment file.If yes then show me.

Comment: posted the production.rb in the main thread. but what do you mean by properly build?

Comment: check the production log file which will give more information about the error

Comment: Production and development environments use different databases by default. As an option you should run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: ck3g This was what I was missing! I am brand spankin new to Rails and I didn't see that in deploy instructions anywhere except for this comment. I really like Rails but it sure seems like documentation is scattered and has some holes. Still, I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure you have ran `$ bundle install`. If this doesn't succeed, go to your production environment and connect to your server using ssh and `$ tail -f log/production.log` in your current production app.

This will generate an output which might show an error.

If this doesn't show an error in the log/ directory do `$ ls -la` if there are any passenger.error files open the latest and check for errors there.

Hope this helped you out!

---

In addition to log/production.log, you should also look at the web server error log, typically `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Some errors are written there instead. More information can be found in the Troubleshooting section of the Passenger manual:

- [Nginx version](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_generic_troubleshooting_tips)
- [Apache version](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_generic_troubleshooting_tips)
- [Standalone version](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#_generic_troubleshooting_tips)

Comment: Yes it helped, I had an error, because of a lacking database entry and because It ran in production mode the exception wasn't shown...

Comment: FINALLY, LIVE FEED ERRORS... THANK YOU

Comment: For me the "/var/log/apache2/error.log" worked, the production log was empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I was struggling with a similar type of problem and found that by changing config.consider_all_requests_local to true in config/environments/production.rb, I could get the error message to display in production and see what the actual problem was. Obviously, change it back once you've fixed the problem.

Comment: This would provide a solution on new apps however I strongly suggest not using this method when you are hosting a high traffic application. just checking the stack trace of an error in your production.log is most clean.

Comment: A great suggestion to diagnose the underlying issue. Mine was `AssetNotFound`

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same problem, same message, 500 error code, but it was in development mode and nothing useful was logged. And it only happened at one of my colleges setup.

The problem were non-ASCII chars (here: umlauts like ü, ß and so on) within strings. We now simply translate everything with `I18n.t('text_to_translate')` (find the corresponding yaml translation file in /config/locales/, for more info on I18N see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with django being installed in a passenger environment.

The problem for me was that in the `passenger_wsgi.py` file the path to the custom virtualenv Python installation was wrong.