# Deploying Ruby on Rails on Bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting

Does anyone here know how to deploy a Ruby app on Bluehost? I am having quite a problem with this. Everytime I put my files inside the folder where my domain is pointing at, it always giving me a 403 error when I try to visit the website.

Comment: What ruby server are you running? My guess is that you aren't, but without more information it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Bluehost has it as ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 8):

It's so painful. The [instructions](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails) are incomplete. There are a bunch of things to get caught on like broken versions of *sass*, assets not [pre-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616405/actionviewtemplateerror-application-css-isnt-precompiled-rails), database configuring, how to [restart the serve](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/182146)r, the root directory for *passenger*, [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513450/were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-with-rails-apache-passenger).
I had problems with all of those things. I had to come here (Stack Overflow) to find most of the answers.
My site still runs in dev but not in production. The BH support is not much help. THey should call it BlueWordPressHost because that is who they are supporting.

Look in the `<rails_root>/log` directory for clues.

I'm not willing to switch over to Heroku and use postgres, I tried it but in reality your just dealing with another set of problems setting it up.

Answer (score 5):

Give it a look -> [Ruby on Rails Setup with Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails).
You cant just drop your Files in a folder.

Although Bluehost does a great job, i recommend you using [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for deploying Ruby on Rails Apps.

Deploying with Heroku is quite Easy -> [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: definitely second *not* recommending bluehost for rails [I did it by installing a custom ruby instance but gave up eventually for performance reasons: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2013/06/goodbye-bluehost-for-rails ]

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions in the [Ruby on Rails Setup](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails) as [The Mini John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609496/the-mini-john) referenced and it worked.  They use [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) to allow you to deploy any [rack based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28web_server_interface%29) application. However, I did have to manually install my gem dependencies.  This is probably not a scalable solution for a production application with many users.  However, if you already have bluehost as a hosting provider and are willing to maintain your own server and deal with possible latency issues and downtime, it may be worth it for you.  Here is my Ruby on Rails 4.0 "Hello World" application deployed to bluehost: http://hello.getplanit.com.