# ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, passenger

I'm getting below in my production server:

```
Started GET "/" for 101.160.190.206 at 2013-09-05 00:11:28 +1000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    4:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    5:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Tools" %></title>
    6:     <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Tools" %>">
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    9:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    10:     <%= yield(:head) %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__153052184121312410_16560580'
```

I ran `rake assets:precompile` and it seems to compile correctly as I can see in the assets file but I'm still getting

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

error.

I'm not sure where it went wrong...

Comment: where did you run the precompile? on the server? or your localbox?  how do you deploy to production?

Comment: Ran on the server on directory it was deployed

Comment: did you restart the server after you compiled?

Comment: You are right. I did restart and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't modified anything `application.css` should be included by default into assets, so try running:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

instead of

```
rake assets:precompile
```

which takes default environment which is by default `development`. At least that was an 'issue' I've faced several weeks ago, so maybe it's same in that case.