# bluehost Ruby on Rails Application shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, shared-hosting

I'v started working on **bluehost (shared hosting)** from yesterday and deploying an **Rails Application**.
Available **Ruby 1.9.3** and **Rails 3.2.13**

1) I'm unable to `install bundle` (it through error **rake(11.0) can not load ,bundler can not continue**) (How can I install new `gems` in my project without any error)

2) How can I restart the Rails Server on blue host which is connected on my Subdomain.

Please help!

Comment: This is two questions. Please raise them separately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying Ruby on Rails on Bluehost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305883/deploying-ruby-on-rails-on-bluehost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your gems are installed on your bluehost shared hosting account, some of them need root access to install and resolve their dependencies.

However, on a shared account there no root access allowed for your account. You need to contact support or maybe you need to buy VPS plan.